# javascript - is current date x days since given date?

Tags: javascript

There are a thousand topics on dates and how annoying they are to use in javascript. Below are a few that I used to get to the point I am at..

[javascript date + 7 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741632/javascript-date-7-days)

[add x days to given date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767704/script-that-adds-x-days-to-a-given-date)

but it is either too early and my brain is fogged, or I am just struggling with some of the logic here. I've created 3 methods, or functions rather...

```
Date.prototype.daysTo = function(target) {
    var divisor = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    return (((this - target) / divisor));
};
Date.prototype.hoursTo = function(target) {
    var divisor = (1000 * 60 * 60);
    return (((this - target) / divisor));
};
Date.prototype.minutesTo = function(target) {
    var divisor = (1000 * 60);
    return (((this - target) / divisor));
};
```

My basic goal is to save a date (using Date().toUTCString()) like this `var d = new Date().toUTCString();` and then store that somewhere (where it is stored is irrelevent)

now then, that date is saved, everyone has a party, there are chicken wings etc.

I want to fetch the date later, how it is retrieved is also irrelevent. Just assume it is '`d`'. Now this is the part that should be excessively simple, and I've done it a half billion times in C#, but for heaven only knows what reason I am struggling to repeat it in javascript.

I want to take an integer (`7`) and then see if another given date (in most situations, 'today') is `n days since d`.

I tried...

```
var today = new Date().ToUTCString();

var result = today.daysTo(d);
```

and I thought this would give me the appropriate value, but I am just getting strange 'undefined' values.

Can someone help me out? This should be really simple and I honestly don't know why I am struggling so much with it, but for whatever reason I am, and it is driving me batty. I think I am missing something very obvious.

Here we go, a better code snippet.

```
Date.prototype.daysTo = function(target) {
    var divisor = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    return (((this - target) / divisor));
};
Date.prototype.hoursTo = function(target) {
    var divisor = (1000 * 60 * 60);
    return (((this - target) / divisor));
};
Date.prototype.minutesTo = function(target) {
    var divisor = (1000 * 60);
    return (((this - target) / divisor));
};

var past = new Date(2011,7,1).toUTCString();
var present = new Date().toUTCString();

alert(present.daysTo(past));
```

I get the error

> present has no function 'daysTo'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have defined the `daysTo()` function as a method of the Date object, but you are trying to call it on a string.

That is, `var present = new Date().toUTCString();` results in `present` being a string, since `toUTCString()` returns a string.

I would do all of the Date arithmetic before calling `toUTCString()`, like:

```
var past = new Date(2011,7,1);
var present = new Date();

alert(present.daysTo(past));
```

Only call `toUTCString()` when storing (and possibly displaying) the date.

Also, don't know if this is an option, depending on how you are storing it, but you may want to store it as a Date object, rather than a string.

Comment: Hrnm. so how can I get the UTC Date/Time as a Date instead of a string?

Comment: var storedDateString = {pull utc date string from storage}; \n var storedDate = new Date(storedDateString);

Comment: ugh - can't figure out how to get a line break in there... :-( ... ignore the '\n'